# connecting 2 or more tableviews to display information from the same nsarray

Tags: nsarray

I'm confussed and tried many different things to eliminate the errors im facing.

I have a NSArray of proteins, in my storyboard i have two seperate table views that i wish to both display the protiens array.

i am having errors at -(UITableViewcell *) and @end of which there are two } errors.

If anyone can help please find my ViewController.m code below: (Please disregard the segue coding near the end)

```
#import "JViewController.h"
#import "OneViewController.h"
#import "TwoViewController.h"

@interface JViewController ()

@end

@implementation JViewController
{
    NSArray *proteins;
}

@synthesize tableView1;
@synthesize tableView2;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    proteins = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Chicken", @"Turkey", @"Ham", @"Steak", @"Pork   Chop",     @"Roast Lamb", @"Salmon", @"Egg", @"Lentils", @"Kidney Beans", nil];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == tableView1) {
        return [proteins count];
    {
    if (tableView == tableView2) {
        return [proteins count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ProteinCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    if (tableView1 == tableView2)
    {
        proteins;
    }
    else
    {
        proteins;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [proteins objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showMealOneDetail"])
    {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    OneViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.proteinName = [proteins objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Big thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have two open brackets here, close this one:

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == tableView1) {
        return [proteins count];
   ->> {
    if (tableView == tableView2) {
        return [proteins count];
    }
}
```

And what do you mean with this?

```
    if (tableView1 == tableView2)
{
    proteins;
}
else
{
    proteins;
}
```

Try this:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ProteinCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    cell.textLabel.text = [proteins objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Have you been able to show anything in one tableview? Make sure you have connected dataSource and delegate.

Hope it helps =)